Addressing Irregular Time Intervals of observations in Event Study/Staggered Difference-in-Difference Method
I am conducting a study using an event study/staggered difference-in-difference (DiD) method. My dataset consists of observations with irregular time intervals: some individuals have daily observations, others have weekly observations, but a significant number have completely irregular observations that can be separated by a year or more.
I am concerned that these irregular time intervals might introduce bias into my analysis. Are there any academic papers or research that address this specific issue within the context of difference-in-difference methods? Most of the literature I have found pertains to moving average models for time series data, which does not directly apply to my situation. Any guidance or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

These kinds of problems can be treated as missing data problems. They can be handled either by imputation or removal of data - the latter usually under the missing-at-random assumption. If you only have yearly observations for many units, imputation would very likely be challenging. Also, removal is likely to be a lot less time-consuming. So I would start in that ballpark, but I do not know any specific imputation method designed for your problem. I doubt it exists.
